# Why is this reference ambiguous?

Tags: scala, scala-swing

```
import swing._

object PeerTest extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    val p = peer.getMousePosition 
  }
}
```

gives

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method getMousePosition in class Container of type (x$1: Boolean)java.awt.Point
and  method getMousePosition in class Component of type ()java.awt.Point
match expected type ?
val p = peer.getMousePosition
```

but adding the type

```
val p: Point = peer.getMousePosition
```

makes it ok. Why?

**edit:** causes problem:

```
class A {
  def value() = 123
}

class B extends A {
  def value(b: Boolean) = 42  
}

object Main extends App {
  println ((new B).value) 
}
```

doesn't cause problem:

```
class A {
  def value() = 123
  def value(b: Boolean) = 42  
}

class B extends A {}

object Main extends App {
  println ((new B).value) 
}
```

So I think the answer has to explain why it only occurs when the methods are in different classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two methods `getMousePosition` one without and one with a boolean parameter.

Without a type annotation Scala does not know if you want a reference to the method in one parameter (a `Function1` object) or if you want to invoke the one without parameters (resulting in a `Point`).

Specifying the expected type clarifies your intend.

Using `getMousePosition()` should work as well.

Comment: So we can break people's code if we decide to add overloading methods to a class... this doesn't seem very good. I thought putting a `_` after the method was the way to make it a partially applied function.

Comment: @Luigi There are many ways to break people's code by adding overloads, this is just one more way.

Comment: @Daniel @retronym There might be reasons to avoid overloading but I don't think this case is ambiguous, since it wouldn't be interpreted as a function if the zero-arg overload didn't exist (unless a `_` is added). It looks like a bug to me, unless there's some reason I don't know of why it should behave this way.

Answer (score 4):

A more direct way to refer to the desired overloaded alternative is by including the empty argument list.

```
peer.getMousePosition()
```